# How to make a library to work in React Native environement?

Tags: react-native

I'm new in React Native, please bear with me. I have a library, which works fine in NodeJS and in browser. I would like to make it usable in React Native too.
I created an example project, imported the library but it threw an exception - *Unable to resolve module `http`*. If I try to import the browser version, `document` is not available.

Since then I'm scratching my head - how am I supposed to make my library to work in React Native if neither the core NodeJS modules, nor `document` are available?

Comment: please edit your question and mention the library name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native does not have access to Node.js modules such as `http`, so any code that relies on that functionality is not going to work. You will have to remove or replace it. As for `document`, `window` and other DOM-specific APIs, RN does not use a DOM at all, instead it uses its own rendering mechanism that is coupled to the native APIs. You will also have to remove all those calls and replace them with React Native-compatible ones.

Comment: Okay... and how do I know that the code is running in React Native environment so I can load something else instead `http`? Or maybe this is not possible and I have to create a special build for React Native?

Comment: This one I figured out by myself - there is navigator.product

Comment: Cool! I did not know about that one, so we both learnt something :)